# how to move div children to its parent with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I've been trying to do this for a while, I know it's easy but I just can't figure out what part I am doing wrong, for example let's say we have this code, which is generated somewhere else, it's faulty and needs repair:

```
<ul>
<li>menu</li>
<div id='languages'>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>item a</li>
    <li>item b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</ul>
```

obviously, I want to move the content of the inside ul to be in the outside ul, then remove the div, this is what I am trying now, and not working:

```
var el = $('#languages');
el.parent().append(el.find('li'));
el.remove();
```

can I know what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Putting `list-items` (`li`) outside of `ul` or `ol` isn't semantic.

Comment: Looks like it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LWZYJ/

Comment: @Itay i guess it seems like he wants to make the inner lis as a part of outer ul

Comment: @PSL Now that you've mentioned it it makes sense... Not really clear though

Comment: @PSL yes exactly and the funny thing is that mode code is working on jsfiddle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#languages ul li').unwrap().unwrap();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEAEJ/1/)**

This way li's inside the inner ul will be a part of the outer one. unwrap will unwrap itself i.e fist unwrap will remove `ul` and second will unwrap `div`.

Also by the way, need to mention that your source html is invalid, `ul` cannot have `div` as direct descendant.

Comment: This will remove `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`

Comment: @Sergio "content of the inside ul to be in the outside ul" in the Post.

Comment: really nice one, although my code turned out to be correct but you really deserve an up vote

Comment: @LabibIsmaiel that probably could be because you haven't wrapped your code in DOM ready. wrap `$(function(){code here});` and try